# How do you slice a meshgrid array of points in numpy so that the order is maintained?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a grid of points in numpy that I am trying to interpolate. The code that generates them is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)[:, None]  # inject trailing singleton for broadcasting
a, b = np.mgrid[0:1:0.1, 0:1:0.1]

#create dose distribution matrix 
D = a.ravel() * x**2 + b.ravel() * x + 1

#perform SVD Decomposition  
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(D)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

c0 = V[0]
#ax.scatter(a, b, c0)

#delete some points for testing interpolation
a_trng = a.ravel()
a_trng = np.append(a_trng[0:50], a_trng[70:100])
b_trng = b.ravel()
b_trng = np.append(b_trng[0:50], b_trng[70:100])

a_test = a_trng[50:70]
b_test = b_trng[50:70]


c0_trng = np.append(c0[0:50], c0[70:100])
c0_test = c0[50:70]

rbfi = Rbf(a_trng, b_trng, c0_trng)
ci = rbfi(a, b)
ax.scatter(a_trng, b_trng, c0_trng)
ax.scatter(a_test, b_test, c0_test)
```

I am trying to remove some points, the `test` points to create `trng` points for the interpolation. However, the ```test`` points are moved. How can I slice the meshgrid so that this doesn't occur? [image: points are moved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
a_test = a.ravel()[50:70]
b_test = b.ravel()[50:70]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works. Why should it be different from my version, though?